# Arithmetic operation underflowed or overflowed outside of an unchecked block - hardhat test

Tags: solidity, hardhat, solidity-0.8.x, unittesting

I created a vault contract in solidity v0.8.11:

```
struct User {
  uint256 totalAmount;
}

mapping(address => mapping(address => User)) Users;

function withdraw(
   address _token,
   address _user,
   uint256 _amount
) external {
   User storage user = Users[_token][_user];
   user.totalAmount -= _amount;

   // transfer access token amount to the user
   IERC20(_token).safeTransfer(_user, _amount);
}
```

When I call withdraw() in the hardhat test script, I get this error:
`Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with panic code 0x11 (Arithmetic operation underflowed or overflowed outside of an unchecked block)`

The contract A has `250000` token, the user's `totalAmount` is also `250000`, and I tried to withdraw `50000` token from this contract.

**I already know about solution which uses `unchecked { ... }`, but it doesn't change the `userPositoin.totalAmount`.**

I can't understand why this happens. Please help me if you have a experience in such case.

Comment: Must be accessing the wrong mapping element. Are you sure that [_token][_user] are existing location and are in correct order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be *Users[_token][_user]* wasn't actually set then the operation *user.totalAmount -= _amount;* resulted in an underflow (i.e. 0 - 50000)

It costs some gas, but maybe just put a simple require:

```
require(user.totalAmount >= _amount, "Empty wallet");
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I am not sure why this happens. Before executing `withdraw`, the totalAmount appears to `250000` but inside the function, it is `0`.

Comment: That implies that wherever you were supposed to assign *Users[_token][_user]* it didn't get assigned, could you link your code?

Comment: I did figure out the reason. As you said, Users[_token][_user] wasn't actually set. lol

At first, I set the mapping keys as it looks like **_user => (_token => User)**, but tried to get user with **_token => (_user => User)**. It was just my fault.

`mapping(address => mapping(address => User)) Users;`

Now I fixed the line and everything is OK, thanks @FudgyDRS.